# Нужно чтобы массив был динамическим и без исключений

Tags: c

Нужно чтобы программа записывала элементы пока не поступит пустое значение (сейчас она перестаёт когда видит ноль ) . Пожалуйста , помогите. я новичок в этом деле

```
int main()
    {
      int *a = NULL, i = 0;
      int elem,j;
      do {
        scanf("%d", &elem);
        a = (int*)realloc(a, (i + 1) * sizeof(int));
        a[i] = elem;
        i++;
      }
      while (elem !=NULL);
      for ( j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("%d ", a[j]);
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Ну, например, можно считывать сначала строку (fgets()/gets()), а потом из нее добывать числа через sscanf() или atoi(). И если строка окажется пустой (или из одних пробелов, или букв) - прекращать чтение данных. PS: да, тут все просто ненавидят gets() (она опасная, да), поэтому ее лучше не использовать, а пользоваться fgets(). Естественно, все возможные ошибки надо проверять (а не как у Вас с realloc() ) - кто сказал, что он выделит нужную память?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int main()
{
   char *a=0;
   int i=0;
   int j;
   char elem;
   do{
    scanf("%c",&elem);
    a = (char*)realloc(a,(i+1)*sizeof(char));
    a[i] = elem;
    i++;
   }
    while (elem!=' ');
        for ( j = 0; j < i; j++)
            printf("%c", a[j]);
    return 0;
}
```